# how to find average with respective to the cell difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

so i have some data in column A, like this,

```
(A1)12 (B1) 
       (B2)1
       (B3)2
       (B4)3
(A5)15 (B5)4
       (B6)1
(A7)32 (B7)2
```

but after each value in column, there are some random number of empty cell and then another value. so the formula i am using is to calculate data between A1 and A5 in column C is

```
 =$A$1+(B2/4)*($A$7-$A$1)
```

same for the next two values in column A between A5 and A7. ,
but the thing is i have a very high amount of data, is there any option that i dont have to specify cell in the above formulae, it automatically selects the non empty cells in the formulae along with their cell numbers.and cell difference.[image]![enter image description here]

Comment: Can you post a better data example? an image. Also, please, post what would be the right result

Comment: couldn't let me upload picture :(  it says i need 10 reputation points to upload image

Comment: You got 11 reputation right now.

Comment: mathematical expression in C3 would be like.  22.25 + ( 1/5)*( 28.25 - 22.25)   and in C4  22.25 + (2/5)*( 28.25 - 22.25).  here we had to lock the upper and lower values, but the problem is for the next two values we have specify values again, is there any method that we dont have to specify, it automatically takes the next non empty cell.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your time. really appreciate it.... i have found a trick, i have just divided the formula in parts by taking extra colums and finally combined them.